# Install another Perl in Linux?

Tags: linux, perl, perlbrew

In our development environment, another team is using default Perl. So we shouldn't touch it. How do I install another Perl? How do I install Perl modules using [CPAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN)?

Comment: best is install a whole perl for yorself. `curl -L http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash` - check this page http://perlbrew.pl

Comment: Thanks for quick reply jm666. I'm new to linux. Can you please give little more information in detail?

Comment: Probably everything what you need to know is already nicely written in the site: http://perlbrew.pl

Comment: Why was this voted off topic? "are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." I would argue that Perl is in fact primarily used for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download and install Perl from source. You may download Perl from http://www.perl.org/get.html.

In order to use another `cpan` from another Perl version you may not type "cpan" due to the fact that your Linux user will execute the default locations. Instead you have to execute your "alternate" `cpan` with the full alternate path. Execute with root and clear the hidden `cpan` folder from ".cpan" from user home.

Answer (score 6):

`anyenv` is a great platform to install local versions of all the great open environments, Perl included:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/riywo/anyenv ~/.anyenv
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.anyenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'eval "$(anyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile  # change profile if needed
$ exec $SHELL -l
```

This will set up `anyenv`. From here, you will install plenv, the Perl environment tool. Each of the environment tools allows you to manage that languages different installed versions.

```
$ anyenv install plenv
```

Now we can work with the plenv tool...

List available Perl versions:

```
$ plenv install --list
```

Install the Perl 5.18.2 binary:

```
$ plenv install 5.18.2 -Dusethreads
```

Change global default Perl to 5.18.2:

```
$ plenv global 5.18.2
```

Change local project Perl to 5.18.2:

```
$ plenv local 5.18.2
```

Run this command after installing a CPAN module, containing an executable script:

```
$ plenv rehash
```

Install cpanm to the current Perl:

```
$ plenv install-cpanm
```

Install any modules you need from CPAN with

```
$ cpanm JSON
```

I use Carton to manage dependencies within a project and recommend you take a look at it.

Now that you have `anyenv`, remember you can explore different versions of other languages too. `anyenv` is a priceless tool.

```
$ anyenv install --list
Available **envs:
  denv
  jenv
  luaenv
  ndenv
  phpenv
  plenv
  pyenv
  rbenv
```

Answer (score 3):

That's what **[perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/)** is about.

After installing perlbrew, e.g. via

```
$ curl -L http://install.perlbrew.pl | bash
```

(or App::perlbrew from CPAN), you can use

```
$ perlbrew install perl-5.18.2
$ perlbrew switch perl-5.18.2
```